# How to delete website theme

Tags: admin, configuration, websites

I have problem with my website. On main site I got theme's head and I want to delete it. Which files should I delate to get clean website with my content only?

[image]

Comment: enable template path hint and find head . goto that bloac and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a **head**, is a **header**, I don't know why you want to hide a header ? maybe you have some error on it you just have to fix it. otherwise if you always want to remove it, go to

```
app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/layout/local.xml
```

then put this code before `</default>`

```
<remove name="header"/> //this one remove the header in all pages with logo, search bar, minicart, etc...
```

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but i think the white square that you show is **top links block**, you can remove it like this:

```
<reference name="header">
    <remove name="top.links"/>
</reference>

</default>
```

The path to header : `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/page/html/header.phtml`

**Nb:** some theme use several headers, you can find them in exemple: `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/page/html/header/header4.phtml`

To find the right one, please check your theme settings or enable a template path hint in admin.